# combine two scatterplots in one

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I am new to R.I need to combine two scatter plots, plot(x1, y1) plot(x2, y2) and would like to plot them in the same figure. How can I do it? I tried with the following code.

```
df
    x1  y1  x2  y2
1  3.6 6.7 5.8 8.9
2 12.7 9.2 8.6 9.0
3  5.8 8.9 7.9 8.7
4   NA  NA 9.0 4.5
5   NA  NA 6.0 9.0
 x1= df$x1
 x2=df$x2
 y1=df$y1
 y2=df$y2
 d1 <- data.frame(x = x1, y = y1)
 d2 <- data.frame(x = x2, y = y2)
 library(reshape2)
 d3 <- rbind(melt(d1, id.vars = "x1") , melt(d2, id.vars = "x1"))
Error: id variables not found in data: x1
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(d3, aes(x1, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
+     geom_point() + labs(x = "x", y = "y")+ xlim(0,100) + ylim(0,100) +
+     scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), labels = c("d1", "d2"))
Error in ggplot(d3, aes(x1, y = value, colour = variable)) : 
  object 'd3' not found
```

your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look at the error messages. You might find that hard to believe, but they are there to help you. And the first error clearly indicates the problem. (Why do you use `melt` there at all?)

Comment: Use ggplot, but use the different aesthetics on two geom_points. Something like: ggplot() + geom_point(data, aes(x1,y1)) + geom_point(data, aes(x2,y2))

Comment: @Guido167 That's not the canonic way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x1 <- 1:5
y1 <- 11:15
x2 <- 5:1
y2 <- 11:15
df <- data.frame(x1, y1, x2, y2)

ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y1)) + geom_point(aes(x = x2, y = y2)
```

[Here's the basic plot that is generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsa8M.png)

Comment: as already mentioned in the comments, while this probably works it's much better to put all data into one dataframe first before plotting. Saves a lot of hassle with legends.

Comment: @gaurav Thank you for your answer. How can I give color to the points on scatterplot?

Comment: @george - Use scale_color_manual() or scale_fill_manual() from ggplot2 package.
E.g.   p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "green")) ;where p is your plot.